# Excluding certain property values in inline query

Tags: negation, semantic-mediawiki

I use the three values (=pages) `A`, `B`, `C` for the property `is of type`.

Some pages have exactly one value for `is of type`, some pages have all three values.

I want to `#ask` for pages that are of type `A` *without* being of type `B` and `C`.

I tried the following inline query:

```
{{#ask: [[Is of type::A]] [[Is of type::!B]] [[Is of type::!C]]}}
```

But it doesn’t work as intended: it lists all pages that are of type `A`, including those that are of type `B`/`C` in addition.

Answer (score 2):

Semantic Mediawiki isn't good at subtractive queries. Your query translates in English to:

Find me every page that has all of these:
-An instance of property "Is of type" equal to A
-An instance of property "Is of type" not equal to B
-An instance of property "Is of type" not equal to C

Now here's the "gotcha": Suppose you have a page that "Is of type" A, B, and C.
-It is of type A.
-It is of a type that isn't B, namely A and C.
-It is of a type that isn't C, namely A and B.

It fits all of your conditions, and goes in the result.

I run into these types of problems often. My wiki actually has several templates for subtracting query results.

Comment: I see, thank you. Could you show an example for such a "subtraction" template that helps in the example case (A without B/C), or would it be too complex?